# QNetworkReply reply has no members in finishedSlot

Tags: c++, web-services, qt

Qt Creator is used as the ide for this small app that is being developed

I am attempting to use QNetworkAccessManager to retrieve some information from a website.  After the request is 'posted' to the web, the finished() signal is triggered, however the pointer that is passed to the finishedSlot() function does not appear to be pointing to an instantiated object, it is just address of the ponter.  The code for the button click that starts the request and the code for the finishedSlot() method is shown below.

In the watch window, I would have expected to see a triangle next to 'reply' that when expaned would show all the data member of QNetworkReply object.  Instead it has a single value of @0x80c770 which looks like the pointer address.

I'd appreciate input from anyone who can help me to understand why my pointer doesn't appeart to be pointing the the QNetworkReply object.

```
void MainWindow::on_btnGetOAuthToken_clicked()
{


    QUrl serviceUrl("https://api.ProPhotoWebsite.com/services/oauth/authorize.mg");
    QUrl postData;
    postData.addQueryItem("method", "ProPhotoWebsite.auth.getRequestToken");
    postData.addQueryItem("oauth_consumer_key", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"); //example key
    postData.addQueryItem("oauth_nonce",QUuid::createUuid().toString());
    postData.addQueryItem("oauth_signature_method","PLAINTEXT");  
    postData.addQueryItem("oauth_signature","999999999999999999999999999"); //example
    postData.addQueryItem("oauth_timestamp", QString::number(QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()/1000));
    postData.addQueryItem("oauth_version","1.0");

    //...
    QNetworkRequest request(serviceUrl);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
                      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // Call the webservice
    QNetworkAccessManager *nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));
    nam->post(request,postData.encodedQuery());

}

void MainWindow::finishedSlot(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    // Reading attributes of the reply
    // e.g. the HTTP status code
    QVariant statusCodeV =
            reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
    // Or the target URL if it was a redirect:
    QVariant redirectionTargetUrl =
            reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);
    // see CS001432 on how to handle this

    // no error received?
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {

        QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();  // bytes
        QString string(bytes); // string
        ui->lblWarning->setText(string);

    }
    else
    {
        // handle errors here
    }

    // need to dispose reply
    delete reply;
}
```

Comment: You must not delete the reply in finishedSlot(), as the control returns to the point where finished() was emitted, then operating on a deleted "this" object -> crash. Use deleteLater() for safe deletion (it schedules the deletion in the event loop).

Comment: Also you create new Network Access Manager everytime you want to create new query. Use one instance of QNetworkAccessManager for whole class. It is reusable and you wont leak memory this way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Frank and Kamil.  I have since found a very well done library that will do the OAuth authenticaion:  [link](http://www.d-pointer.com/solutions/qt-meego-symbian/kqoauth/)KQOauth